# Scrapy spider can't seem to find the xpath for the next page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

My spider can crawl anything that I want in the first page, but when it tries to find the xpath for the next page I get the error that index is out of range. I tested in shell, and xpath seems fine, so now I am lost on what to do.

```py
rom scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from lrrytas.items import LrrytasItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class LrrytasSpider(Spider):
    name = "lrrytas"
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.lrytas.lt/']
    start_urls = ["http://www.lrytas.lt/?id=14355922181434706286&view=6"]
    rules = (
       Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
       Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//*[@class="comment-box-head"]/*')), callback='parse_comments_follow_next_page', follow=True)
)
    def parse(self, response):
     sel = Selector(response)
     site = sel.xpath('//*[@class="comment"]/*')
     node = sel.xpath('//*[@class="comments"]/*')

     for i in range(0, len(site), 2):
       item = LrrytasItem()
       item['name'] = node[i].xpath('*/div[contains(@class, "comment-nr")]/text()').extract()[0]
       item['ip'] = node[i].xpath('*/*/div[contains(@class, "comment-ip")]/text()').extract()[0]
       item['time'] = node[i].xpath('*/*/div[contains(@class, "comment-time")]/text()').extract()[0]
       item ['comment'] = site[i + 1].xpath('descendant-or-self::text()').extract()[0]
       yield item

    def parse_comments_follow_next_page(self, response):
        next_page = xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Kitas >>") and contains(@href, "id")]/@href')
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
            yield Request(url, self.parse)
```

Edit: I made the cycle more automative then manual with `len()`

Comment: on `parse_comments_follow_next_page`, are you sure `xpath(...)[9]` returns a list? I think not, and when you do `next_page[0].extract()` it may throw **IndexError**. Please double check first

Comment: Sorry, maybe I worded it a bit wrongly, what I meant is that I want it to chose a link which is in [here](http://i.imgur.com/OUxYvaY.png), so it would go to a next page of comments, and [this](http://i.imgur.com/lEr3his.png) is what I get in shell for my xpath.

Comment: normally best way to do it is to grab that link by locating text and check href like `.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Kitas >>") and contains(@href, "id")]/@href').extract()[0]`, and catch **IndexError** for no more links found... This approach will be more robust. Regarding to the error you have, try changing the xpath in **restricted_xpath** I think that could be the culprit

Comment: also, post with your error details (trace... etc). I need to be away for a while, and will come back and help if you haven't solved this yet by then, good luck :)

Comment: Ok I fixed the **IndexError**, it was a calculation error on my part, in the for cycle, instead of 52 cycles, it had to be 50, but now it still won't crawl the next page. This time with no error message for directions.

Comment: I think it ignores for some reason the `def parse_comments_follow_next_page` section. Probably that is why my spider just scrapes the first page and then stops.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CrawlSpider` rule and the `XPath` for the next_page check seem to me like not fitting well together. So I'd like to suggest to use a simple `Spider` and take care of the next page requests manually. I've compiled some code that shows how to do that:

```
import scrapy

class Comment(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    ip = scrapy.Field()
    time = scrapy.Field()

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'lrytas'
    allowed_domains = ['www.lrytas.lt']
    start_urls = ['http://www.lrytas.lt/?id=14355922181434706286&view=6']

    def parse(self, response):

        xpath_comments = '//div[@class="comments"]/div[@class="comment"]'
        sel_comments = response.xpath(xpath_comments)
        for sel in sel_comments:
            item = Comment()
            item['name'] = ' '.join(sel.xpath('.//div[@class="comment-nr"]//text()').extract())
            item['time'] = ' '.join(sel.xpath('.//div[@class="comment-time"]//text()').extract())
            # Other item fields go here ...
            yield item

        # Check if there is a next page link ...
        xpath_NextPage = './/a[contains(.,"Kitas >>")][1]/@href' # Take on of the two links
        if response.xpath(xpath_NextPage):
            # If YES: Create and submit request
            url_NextPage = 'http://www.lrytas.lt' + response.xpath(xpath_NextPage).extract()[0]
            request = scrapy.Request(url_NextPage, callback=self.parse)
            yield request
```